# jquery and replacing word

Tags: jquery, replace

I gotta modify website after some1 on drupal. On this page http://www.plfon.pl/dom/oferta/oferta-plfon-dla-nowych-klient%C3%B3w?qt-dom_oferta_oferta_dla_nowych_tab=3#qt-dom_oferta_oferta_dla_nowych_tab=

when you choose any checkbox the word "brutto" changes to "netto" I've research the whole ftp and have no clue why is this happening. Then I realize its something like replace in jquery so I quickly made something like that

```
   <script type='text/javascript'  src='ttp://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'> </script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
     var j = jQuery.noConflict();
     window.setInterval(function() {
   {
    j('.cena').html(j('.cena').html().replace('netto', 'brutto'));
   }
  }, 800); // checks all 800ms
```

But this doesnt work, any idea why ? I tested with alert and it shows, but this replace not.

Comment: change your code to `j('.cena').html().replace('netto', 'brutto')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're missing a "h" at your jQuery import, so it should be

```
<script type='text/javascript'  src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'> </script>
```

Now the most important:

1. Your application is overrinding the "j" variable name to another thing. So change your variable name "j" to another name, I'll use "myNewJquery".
2. Searching and replacing for each `.cena` manually works fine , you can do this:

   var myNewJquery = jQuery.noConflict();

   ```
   window.setInterval(function() {

       myNewJquery (".cena").each(function(){
         myNewJquery (this).html(myNewJquery (this).html().replace('netto','brutto'));
       });

   }, 800); // checks all 800ms
   ```

If you want to execute just after page loads, try this:

```
var myNewJquery  = jQuery.noConflict();

myNewJquery ( document ).ready(function() {

 window.setInterval(function() {

        myNewJquery (".cena").each(function(){
          myNewJquery (this).html(myNewJquery (this).html().replace('netto','brutto'));
        });

    }, 800); // checks all 800ms

});
```

Comment: so it shud be like that ? 'var j = jQuery.noConflict();
window.setInterval(function() {
  {
       j('.cena').each(function(){
  j(this).html(j(this).html().replace('netto','brutto'));
});
    }
}, 800); // checks all 800ms'    this not working either, nothing happens

Comment: Mateusz, but in your site the word is by default "brutto". Do you want to change this for "netto"? Because in your example you are searching for "netto"..not "brutto". Change "netto" for "brutto" in my given code and see if it works

Comment: ye but its only on the main page, when you chose anything from the left sidebar , the list changes and there is "netto" instead of "brutto"  try to mark any checkbox , then u see

Comment: Mateusz, you are placing this code at the top of your code, right? I think that's why it is not working. Put this code at the END of your file, just before </body> tag is OK. Things need to load before you use'em. I also edited my post to you use the "ready()" function. You can try this too if still not working.

Comment: hm im placing this in the php file , which is responsible for that part of website. And this is putted automaticly in the place of <head> tag. Hm may it be cuz of this part ? 
        j(".cena").each(function(){  in php i gotta change this -> " "  for that ->   ' '  becouse its still not working xD on the other hand i dont think its about position of the code, cuz simple alert function works fine.

Comment: I have edited my post, did you have tried using the second way (with "ready")?

Comment: ye i did, it like no reaction at all, when i tested this with alert , alert shows. what s in my mind now , maybe the quotation marks ?

Comment: You are missing a "h" at "http://" for <script type='text/javascript'  src='ttp://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'> </script>

Comment: ye indeed ;) but still nothing ;) i dont get this at all... hm, this "netto" its actually with a space " netto" may it be the cause ?

Comment: Now that's easy!! in your app you are using "j" after for another thing and break this code. Change the "j" in your code for another string. I edited my post using "myNewJquery" instead "j". And no, there's no problem with the space. The code is working fine, trust me.

Comment: wow man , awesome it works ;) damn, how u figured it out ;) ?

Comment: Using Google Chrome console, learn how to use it brother, it can save your life! That was hard to solve all the problems, isn't?!! but I really enjoyed spending time with you! See ya :)

Comment: ye im using it but.. looks like not quite well ;) however what is more funny just right before i read ur message about this "j" i've read the note from chrome about "j is not object or something". I guess its like mind connection ;) u've found out this and i started to know where shud i look for ;p  have a nice life ;)